# HTTP_Request_2 :: addPostParameter adds extra characters

Tags: php, pear, http-request

So I'm trying to send a POST request with pear *HTTP*_Request_*2*

I'm adding a POST parameter to a request with *addPostParameter* function

```
$request->addPostParameter(array(
         'lgname'=>'Admin',
         'lgpassword'=>'xxx','lgtoken'=>$xmlresponse->login['token']
                        ));
```

however some extra characters appear in POST request body:

```
lgname=Admin&lgpassword=xxx&lgtoken%5B0%5D=6b9c078a99d5e9821ccaa8b3d41bfdef
```

uri decode says that **%5B0%5D** is **[0]** so it looks like
lgtoken[0]=6b9c078a99d5e9821ccaa8b3d41bfdef

, but how does this appear here?? How to get rid of it?\

I need just lgtoken=6b9c078a99d5e9821ccaa8b3d41bfdef

Comment: Maybe $xmlresponse->login['token'] returns an array with just one value and addPostParameter checks if a param has an array assigned. In this case it would generate an array for this param like in your example. Could you just verify/var_dump the content of $xmlresponse->login['token']?

Comment: thank you for response. here is vardump: class SimpleXMLElement#37 (1) { string(32) "7894940ac800b8c1142b83cb176758ca" }.

Comment: You were right.. I tried (string) $xmlresponse->login['token']; and it worked.. Thank you for a hint..